# Regex which selects from string to string

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to delete every comments of a CSS file (`/* */` format) using regex in Sublime Text 3.

I tried `(?s)\/\*[^(?:\*\/)]*\*\/`, `(?s)\/\*(?:[^\*][^\/])*\*\/` and many more, but I can't get the regex to not select a `*/` if it finds one (which would mean the comment is finished).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used came from the link [barq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364347/barq) gave in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910371/4255615), which is: `/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

Also have a look at this guide, which covers your question on removing comments on code: 
http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following:

```
\/\*([\s\S]*)?\*\/
```

[See regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/zV5uM2/1). The key is the character class `[\s\S]` which matches everything including new lines and carriage returns. The text of the comment (without the opening and closing codes) will be captured in the capture group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those regex do not work for some reason. See my answer for the solution I used. Thank you.